# Is it possible to use a @Resource instance defined in the same @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an example that is something like this

The class `Other` needs an instance of `MyBean` so I'm creating an attribute and using that attribute while creating and `Other`

```
@Configuration 
public SomeClass {

     @Resource 
     private MyBean b;

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean b = new MyBean();
         b.foo(env.getProperty("mb"); // NPE
         return b;
     }

     @Bean 
     public Other other() {
         Other o = new Other(o);
         return o;
     }
}
```

But I'm getting `NullPointerException` while initializing the `myBean` object, I guess that's because the `env` property has not been wired still at that point.

If I don't use the bean and use the method directly everything works well.

```
@Configuration 
public SomeClass {

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         MyBean b = new MyBean();
         b.foo(env.getProperty("mb"); // NPE
         return b;
     }

     @Bean 
     public Other other() {
         Other o = new Other(myBean());
         return o;
     }
}
```

Is it because I'm defining the `@Bean` in the same `@Configuration` class?

Comment: I guess it works properly if you replace the `@Resource` annotation for `@Autowired` in the `b` field?

Comment: @XtremeBiker well yeah, that worked. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of it being interesting as a conceptual question, the way-to-go with the Spring Java configuration would be just to pass the required bean as a parameter, so you'd avoid autowiring beans as fields of a configuration class. If any of your beans happen to require the `MyBean` instance, just provide it as a parameter:

```
 @Bean 
 public Other other(MyBean myBean) {
     Other o = new Other(myBean);
     return o;
 }
```

There's no problem in calling `@Bean` anotated methods from your configuration classes too, as you're doing in your second code snippet, as they're [proxied and cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990468/1199132), so they won't create unecessary instances. However, I tend to follow the code above as it allows the developer knowing the required dependencies in a quick glimpse.

Having said that, for your concrete question `@Autowired` works instead of `@Resource`, but it makes no sense to use any of them in a `@Configuration` class. Just use local method parameters.