# Spring does not use autowired constructor for loading the bean

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have autowired `Address` bean into the constructor of `Employee` bean. And expect when getting instance of `Employee` bean I should get an instance of `Address` inside it. But Spring container is using no-args constructor of `Employee` to return the instance. Below is my code

```
public class Address {
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("inside address");
    }
}

public class Employee {

    private Address address;

    @Autowired
    public Employee(Address address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Employee(){} 

    public Address getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.spring"})
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Employee employee(){
        return new Employee();
    }

    @Bean
    public Address address(){
        return new Address();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
        Employee employee = (Employee)context.getBean("employee");
        // Here add is null !!
        Address add = employee.getAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Autowired should be put on the "private Address address"

Comment: @FeiyuZhou but I want to inject bean through constructor.

Comment: It's not suprising since you're registering bean using @Bean annotation in your Configuration file where you are returning new Employe() using no-args constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no-arg constructor is being used because that's the one that you're calling (`new Employee()`):

```
@Bean
public Employee employee() {
    return new Employee();
}
```

Since you're manually creating the `Employee` instance, rather than having Spring create it for you, you'll also have to pass in the `Address` yourself:

```
@Bean
public Employee employee() {
    return new Employee(address());
}
```

Note that multiple calls to `address()` will in fact [return the same bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990468/803925), rather than multiple new instances, if that was your concern.

Otherwise, the alternative is to have `Employee` annotated with `@Component`, after which Spring will automatically create the bean for you and wire in the `Address` dependency. You get that for free since you have component scanning turned on (assuming that `Employee` is in the package that you're scanning). If you go this route, you can remove the `employee()` bean definition from your config class, otherwise one may end up overriding the other.

Comment: Haven't tried it but I guess he could as well add Address argument to method signature: @Bean Employee employee(Address address) {return new Employee(address);}.

Comment: @pzeszko Yeah I think that works as well, although I didn't immediately see any documentation of that.

Answer (score 0):

`@Component
public class Employee{
 ...
}`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with spring mvc project you have to enable annotation in your **applicationContext.xml** you have to add this annotation `<context:annotation-config>` then you can use **@Autowired** ,if you just work with spring Ioc just add **@Component**  on **Employee** and **Address** Classes