# Jhipster multi-tenancy - Database per tenant

Tags: jhipster, multi-tenant

I want to implement multi-tenancy with Jhipster. In my approach,I want that each tenant’s data to be kept in a separate database instance and is isolated from other tenants.
How to implement that approach using Jhipster ?

Regards

Comment: JHipster won't hep here,  it requires manual coding, have a look at multitenancy in Spring AbstractRoutingDataSource . Be aware that this approach does not scale well for high number of tenants. How many tenants do you plan to have? You will have to manage Liquibase differently.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your feedback. I manage to have 5 or 6 tenants. Will I have performance issues ? 
Yes the issue that I have now is with liquibase. I want that liquibase to update the schema to all the databases.

Comment: No performance issue for your low number of tenants. For liquibase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523971/how-to-set-up-liquibase-in-spring-for-multiple-data-sources