# SpringBootTest : PostgresSQL TestContainer with liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I would like to create integration test, which should use two postgres test containers for different databases.

The problem:
Need to use different liquibase sets for different test containers.

Current situation:
Tests are using liquibase set which is identified by default in the application and this is okay, but I can not assign the second liquibase scheme to the second test container DB.

Expected behavoiur:
**SpringBootTest will run two test containers with differnt liquibase schemes. **

Comment: share some code to view what you did and why it's not working for you

Comment: If you are using two databases in your application, you need to build an additional DataSource and Liquibase configuration besides from the primary configuration.

Comment: You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523971/how-to-set-up-liquibase-in-spring-for-multiple-data-sources