# Different behavior in calling @Bean annotated methods

Tags: java, spring

I am aware of calling `@Bean` annotated methods from within a `@Configuration` as [already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990060/calling-a-bean-annotated-method-in-spring-java-configuration).

But I don't understand why it doesn't work when the bean is overwritten.

I have a legacy class, which I can't modify. It's a configuration and a business bean at the same time. This is a simplified version:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyBean {

    String someMethod() {
        return otherBean() + "|" + otherBean();
    }

    int called = 0;

    @Bean
    Object otherBean() {
        return called ++;
    }
}
```

Inside the `someMethod()` the factory method `otherBean()` is called two times and as far as annotated with `@Bean` the instance should be gotten from the Spring context and therefore should the actual code `return called ++;` be called only once. Expected output from the `someMethod()` should be always `0|0` and it is so indeed in the production.

Trouble comes when I am about to redefine the bean in a unit test:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig//(MyBean.class)
public class BeanTest {

    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;

    @Test
    void testIt() {
        assertEquals("0|0", myBean.someMethod());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {    

        @Bean
        MyBean myBean() {
            return new MyBean();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason could be some additional settings of the `MyBean` instance in the test (not included in the snippet above).

Now, calling `myBean.someMethod()` returns `0|1` instead of `0|0`.

Everything works again (result is `0|0`), when the `TestConfig` configuration is removed and configuration of the test context is set as `@SpringJUnitConfig(MyBean.class)`.

What's different in registering the bean in the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "magic" of proxying method calls annotated with `@Bean` and returning instances from the Spring context happens only in configuration beans (like here: `@SpringJUnitConfig(MyBean.class)`).

But when you create a new instance as `return new MyBean()`, the `@Configuration` annotation is ignored and the object is registered as a normal bean (`@Bean MyBean myBean()`) but not a configuration. That's why the methods calls `otherBean()` create always a new instance.