# Spring: Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

In Spring Java configuration, suppose I want to re-use a `@Bean` in another `@Bean` definition. I can do this either in one file:

```
@Bean
public A buildA() {
    return new A();
}

@Bean
public B buildB() {
    return new B(buildA());
}
```

or I can configure A in one file and autowire it in another file like (field injection for brevity):

```
@Autowired
private A a;

@Bean
public B buildB() {
    return new B(a);
}
```

I wonder, if the two possibilities are exactly the same? For me it looks as if, the first version might instatiate A twice, while the second doesn't.

I am asking this, since in my special use case, A is establishing a connection to a messaging broker and I have several Bs that consume the stream (I use `.toReactivePublisher()` from spring integration in A), and I don't want to connect twice or more to the broker.

Comment: First version does not instantiate A twice, that construction is very common. Spring beans are singleton by default.

Comment: Does this still apply, if I have more than one @Bean of type A?

Comment: Another option is passing `A` as a parameter to `buildB`: `@Bean public B buildB(A a) { return new B(a); }`

Comment: @Jesper Ok I didn't know that. So I suppose I can use `@Qualifier()` for the variable and thus specifiy the bean explicitely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a @Bean annotated method in Spring java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990060/calling-a-bean-annotated-method-in-spring-java-configuration)

Comment: Yes, you can use `@Qualifier` on a parameter.

Comment: @Jesper Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they're exactly the same. Multiple calls to a `@Bean` annotated method will not create multiple instances of the same bean.

For an explanation on why it doesn't happen, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990468/5771446).