# How does Spring handle this bean initialization process?

Tags: spring

Please take a look at this code snippet.

```
package com.example.test.simple;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestConfigOverride.Config.class)
public class TestConfigOverride {
    
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConfigOverride.class);
    
    public static class TestService {
        private static final AtomicInteger instanceIndex = new AtomicInteger(1);
        private final int instanceId;
        public TestService() {
            instanceId = instanceIndex.getAndIncrement();
        }
        public int getInstanceId() {
            return instanceId;
        }
    }
    
    public static class TestWrapperService {
        private TestService testService;
        public TestWrapperService(TestService testService) {
            this.testService = testService;
        }
        public int getInstanceId() {
            return testService.getInstanceId();
        }
    }
    
    @TestConfiguration
    public static class Config {
        @Bean
        public TestWrapperService testWrapperService() {
            return new TestWrapperService(testService());
        }
        @Bean
        public TestService testService() {
            return new TestService();
        }
    }
    
    @Autowired ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        var testServiceBeans = context.getBeansOfType(TestService.class);
        testServiceBeans.forEach((n, s) -> L.debug("Name=" + n + ", InstanceID=" + s.getInstanceId()));
        var testWrapperServiceBeans = context.getBeansOfType(TestWrapperService.class);
        testWrapperServiceBeans.forEach((n, s) -> L.debug("Name=" + n + ", InstanceID=" + s.getInstanceId()));
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
DEBUG 13052 --- [           main] c.e.test.simple.TestConfigOverride       : Name=testService, InstanceID=1
DEBUG 13052 --- [           main] c.e.test.simple.TestConfigOverride       : Name=testWrapperService, InstanceID=1
```

I really don't understand how this happens. I would expect to see a bean with an InstanceID=2 in the logs but instead I see both classes with instanceID=1. How does Spring make this magic happen here? In particular, what happens when a method with @Bean annotation is called from another method in the configuration class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a @Bean annotated method in Spring java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990060/calling-a-bean-annotated-method-in-spring-java-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some magic when calling a `@Bean`-annotated method in a configuration class:

> All @Configuration classes are subclassed at startup-time with CGLIB. In the subclass, the child method checks the container first for any cached (scoped) beans before it calls the parent method and creates a new instance.

[Calling a @Bean annotated method in Spring java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990060/calling-a-bean-annotated-method-in-spring-java-configuration)

So before calling `new TestService()`, Spring checked the container if a TestService bean exists. It found one and returned it instead of creting a new one.

Also note that the default Spring Bean scope is Singleton.
See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes